# GeoServer: caching fails on reprojection

Tags: geoserver

I want to publish the data in the Oracle DBMS.

Since the SRS of the data (which is EPSG:3093) is different from the SRS the client wants (which is EPSG:5179), it must be transformed.

So, I’ve set the layer property on the Edit Layer page as follows:

- Native SRS: EPSG:3093 (Tokyo / UTM zone 52N)
- Declared SRS: EPSG:5179 (Korea 2000 / Unified CS)
- SRS handling: Reproject native to declared

The problem starts now.

When I clicked ‘Compute from data’ for Native Bounding Box, it displays the result coordinates in Declared SRS, no Native SRS.

Is this the correct behavior? Since it is ‘Native Bounding Box’, the values should be in Native SRS.

Anyways when I clicked ‘Compute from native bounds’ for Lat/Lon Bounding Box, it correctly translates from ‘Declared SRS’.
Maybe it is correct to display the Native Bounding Box in Declared SRS then. (weird)

Anyways the client (OpenLayers 3) displays the data correctly.

But another problem remains.

Integrated GeoWebCache refuses to cache the tile images.

When the logging is set to VERBOSE_LOGGING, it logs the following error:
`org.geowebcache.grid.OutsideCoverageException: Coverage [minx,miny,maxx,maxy] is [0, 4097, 6143, 6143, 11], index [x,y,z] is [3101, 2791, 11]`

Since the caching works correctly for the other layers that does not transform the source data (since the data is already in EPSG:5179), that must be the transformation problem. Or another one.

When I see the coverage area of the EPEG:3093 on the Demos / SRS List page on the GeoServer, the area seems to be wrong. (It does not even cover Tokyo!) http://epsg.io/3093 displays the correct one.

Is this the cause of the caching problem?

Does GeoWebCache look for the coverage of the SRS and rejects the out-of-bound request?

My GeoServer version is 2.7.1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've traced the source code from GridSubset.java to GeoServerTileLayer.java and found that the content of the gwc-layers layer file had wrong gridSubset extent coords minY value. (It was too high)

I don't know why... Since I manage the gwc-layers layer files using Git, maybe some file date inconsistency confused GeoServer to sync the values. Or maybe I just broke something. I can only guess... Now after changing that value, caching works.

Answer (score 0):

You should store your data in the native projection as GeoServer will automatically reproject the data when a client makes a request in a different projection.

Then caching and the bbox will work.

Comment: I'm almost sure that my data is in the native projection and reprojection is working, since the data is displayed correctly on the OpenLayers 3 layer. I will read the GeoWebCache source code (and maybe put some log code) to see why it thinks that the tile is out of bounds.

Comment: I've traced the source code from GridSubset.java to GeoServerTileLayer.java and found that the content of the gwc-layers layer file had wrong gridSubset extent coords minY value. (It was too high) I don't know why... Since I manage the gwc-layers layer files using Git, maybe some file date inconsistency confused GeoServer to sync the values. Or maybe I just broke something. I can only guess... Now after changing that value, caching works. Thanks.